# .NET WinForms: Cound not load System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was writing an app for a friend who wanted an easy way to use Morse Code.

I was attempting to use an External Library that I wrote with Morse Code support, and when I try to call it, I get this error, in an External "`Control.cs`" file. I found happened in both Visual Studio and JB Rider, though Visual Studio gives a different error as it can't debug external sources.

My usings are:

```cs
using CainsSharpTools; // <= This is my Library
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

And my function call looks like this:

```cs
private void buttonEncode_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            => textBoxMorse.Text = MorseCode.Parse(textBoxPlain.Text).Value;
```

The error is

```cs
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  at at MorseCoder.Form1.buttonEncode_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
  at at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
  at MorseCoder.Program.Main() in C:\Users\caina\source\repos\MorseCoder\MorseCoder\Program.cs:19
```

Comment: It looks like your library calls something in `System.Runtime`, but you haven't added that reference in your new program.

Comment: You say the error shows up in VS and Rider.  Does it occur on a system upon which the faulting code was compiled?  If so, that's odd.  It indicates that the faulting code has a dependency on a version of an assembly which isn't installed on the machine that the code is running on.  By the way, the code in the exception window is copyable; you could have pasted that message and stack into your question (formatted as "code")

Comment: @MikeH i tried referencing `System.Runtime`, and even added it in the Nuget panel in Rider, but the error still occurred

Comment: Did you confirm it's the same version (4.2.2.0)?

Comment: @Flydog57 The error occurred on my Laptop, which was the system the project was created on (with VS2019). I have also replaced the screenshot with a code block.

Comment: You're probably trying to interface with a .Net Core library from .Net Framework, an especially old one at that too. Upgrade to .Net FW 4.7 and look carefully at what kind of a dependency that library is, and if you set it up correctly it should work.

Comment: @MikeH It appears that the version installed through Nuget is 4.3.1, on Nuget it appears that v4.2.2.0 is not an available version. it jumps from 4.1 to 4.3

Comment: @Blindy Oh, that would explain it, as the Library I wrote is a .NET core one. I assumed it would work in Framework. My .NET FW version is v4.7.2. I set it up by Referencing the DLL and `using` it.

Comment: It should work like that, yeah. Check the output binary folder and make sure the .Net Core runtime is correctly copied there -- you should see a bajillion System.*.dll files in the same folder as that library dll and your executable.

Comment: However if the library you're referencing is yours, you'll be much better off building a multi-framework nuget with both net core and net fw outputs. Interfacing the two otherwise is very costly.

Comment: There only appears to be my Library and `System.Runtime.dll` there along with my exe and the pdb + config file

Comment: If you are compiling to a DLL (aka a "library"), don't target either Framework 4.x or Core N.  Instead, target ".NET Standard" (some version).  Assemblies that target .NET Standard can be consumed by both .NET Framework and .NET Core apps (give or take version numbers): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard.  No, it's not simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed to use .NET Standard with my Lib

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer? What exactly did you do to solve your problem?